# Azure storage config to authorize via microsoft entra

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage

I think I am having a misconfiguration and going through the docs in the pas few days still having the following issue.

- I have a web app which uploads to a blob in azure and it works fine.
- my requirement is only people who are in the azure ad will be authorize to open the files from the link

what I do is after uploading the file it has a hyperlink on the UI which works fine if the anonymous access to the storage is enabled.

But what I want is only people who are in the current active directory will be able to see the link.

So I am logged in and have the current configuration on the Azure storage config

[image]

and then when I click on the link I get [image]

and when it comes to IAM, I added Storage Blob Data Contributor role to my user.

I was wondering what would I be missing?

Comment: have you check the networking tab?

Comment: Public network access = Enabled from all networks

Comment: can you access the file using azure storage explorer and MS entra auth ? i imagine the browser request doesnt include any oauth token

Answer (score 1):

> My requirement is only people who are in the Azure ad will be authorised to open the files from the link

I agree with Thomas's comment, In the browser, the request doesn't include any OAuth token.

In my environment, I had configured as same as you:

**Portal:**

[image]

If you need to authorize the user to authenticate with Azure AD first you need to fetch the oauth token from the user.

You can use the below Python code that will authenticate with Azure ad and authorize you to open the files from the link.

**Code:**

```
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential
import requests

credential=DefaultAzureCredential()
token=credential.get_token("https://storage.azure.com/.default")

url = "https://venkat678.blob.core.windows.net/test/readme.txt"

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token.token, "x-ms-version" :"2023-11-03"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

print(response.text)
```

First in your terminal login **`az-login`** and In the above code are using the **`Azure Identity`** library to authenticate and get a token for accessing Azure Storage.

Token making as **`GET`** request to read the contents of a file `readme.txt` stored in an Azure Blob Storage container `venkat678.blob.core.windows.net/test`.

**Output:**

```
COM Test Suite Readme
---------------------

Running the test suite:
-----------------------
* Open a command prompt
* Change to the "win32com\test" directory.
* run "testall.py".  This will perform level 1 testing.
  You may specify 1, 2, or 3 on the command line ("testutil 3")
  to execute more tests.
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[azure.identity.DefaultAzureCredential class | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-python#azure-identity-defaultazurecredential-get-token)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response, @venkatesan reply is similar to my final solution where instead I made a function in the app where when the user clicks on the link app generates a token that adds to the hyperlink and the link is only valid for 1 second in our case.

```
var uri = new Uri(Filename);
string filenames = Path.GetFileName(uri.LocalPath);

CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(storageConfig.ConnectionString);
CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(storageConfig.ContainerName);
CloudBlockBlob _blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(filenames);

var sas = _blockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new   SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
  {
    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(1),
    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
  }
);
return _blockBlob.Uri.AbsoluteUri + sas;
```